# When using scanf/cin, program works fine in debug mode but gives runtime error

Tags: runtime-error, scanf

I'm trying to take to the following input:

```
1 
4
47 2 4 43577
```

The part of my code that deals with this is:

```
for (scanf("%d", &t); t --; )
{
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (int i = 0, x; i < n; ++ i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        str = to_string(x);
        f4[i] = get_count(str,'4');
        f7[i] = get_count(str,'7');
    }
```

However, with this I get a runtime error, which shows an access violation in the file free.c.

But, when I try to debug it, it runs well in the debug mode and gives the correct answer.

Also, when I output the variable **x** right after I input it, the program works well in runtime as well. This is shown in the following code, which runs fine in runtime as well:

```
for (scanf("%d", &t); t --; )
{
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (int i = 0, x; i < n; ++ i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        cout<<"A"<<i<<" is "<<x<<'\n';
        str = to_string(x);
        f4[i] = get_count(str,'4');
        f7[i] = get_count(str,'7');
    }
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Some of the stackoverflow users are saying that the code runs fine. I'm using VS 2012. Can this be something that is compiler specific?

The complete code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int get_count(string s, char x)
{
    int count = 0;
    int l = s.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < l;i++)
    {
    if (s[i] == x)
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}

void main()
{

int * f4 = new int;
int * f7 = new int;
string * back = new string;

int n = 0;
int t = 0;

string str;

for (scanf("%d", &t); t --; )
{
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for (int i = 0, x; i < n; ++ i)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);
        str = to_string(x);
        f4[i] = get_count(str,'4');
        f7[i] = get_count(str,'7');
    }

    for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < n;j++)
        {
            int c4 = 0;
            int c7 = 0;
            for(int k = i; k <= j;k++)
            {
                c4 += f4[k];
                c7 += f7[k];
            }
            double value = pow((double)c4,(double)c7);

            if(value <= (double)(j - i + 1)&&(c4!=2)&&(c7!=2))
            {
                count++;
                //cout<<"yes"<<'\t';
            }

        }
    }

    cout<<"Ans: "<<count<<'\n';
}   
//getch();
}
```

There are no other variable assignments apart from those in this code.

The exact error that I get with runtime is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7794E3BE (ntdll.dll) in Practice1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x38389246.
```

Comment: Can you include the error message?

Comment: usually if you get a fault when running it outside the debugger but not inside the debugger then you are not allocating memory for one of you variables - in the debugger it will sometimes work in that case - we need to see how you declare the variables.

Comment: From your description most likely you invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Please have a look at the (almost)complete code.

Comment: I'm sorry for so many edits, but now I've included the full code.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the "get_count" function. I think it has something to do with that function. I rewrote that function to return some number and I don't get that error. Try to assert that you are not attempting to use a null pointer in that function.
Works fine on my machine:
Here's what I changed

```
for (int i = 0, x; i < n; ++ i)
{
    scanf("%d",&x);
    stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    str = ss.str();
    f4[i] = get_count(str,'4');
    f7[i] = get_count(str,'7');
}
```

Output:

```
1
4
47 2 4 43577
Ans: 5
```

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested. Instead of calling the function get_count, i just assigned a number to f4[] and f7[], but we have the same problem. I've included everything now, please have a look.

Comment: You code seem to work well on my machine. I don't have c++ 11 though so I had to modify you code to use stringstream instead of to_string(). I don't know if that's where the errors from.

Comment: Thanks, but your hack didn't solve the problem. I tried your way instead of using to_string, i also tried to do it with itoa. I even changed my get_count so that I don't involve strings or char arrays at all in the program!